# Why does model.summary() give shape None when input shape is clear and fixed?

Tags: tensorflow

The code below that is adapted from [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner):

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(len(x_train), -1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, verbose=0)
model.summary()
```

gives output Shape `(32, 10)`, whereas this code

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, verbose=0)
model.summary()
```

gives Output Shape `(None, 10)`.

I'm conscious that 32 means batch size, 10 means the output classes. I'd just like to know where does the `None` come from when input shape is clear and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The first dimension is the number of samples (`batch_size`). Since it should be flexible and work with any number of samples or batch sizes, it is represented as `None`. So, don't worry about it. Your model does not care about the first dimension.

For example in your case input shape is `(28,28)` and output is `(10)`. The model considers `(None,28,28)` and `(None,10)` shapes as input and output. It means that you can feed to the model any number of samples, but each input sample should be `(28,28)`, and the model gives you the same unknown number of samples but each of which with 10 labels. This is the reason that you don't need to set the `batch_size` in the `input_shape` parameter in your first layer.

Another example for the first dimension, is when you train your model, vs. when you predict using that model. For training you may pass an input array say `(10,28,28)`, which means 10 samples with 28,28 size. But when you want to get a prediction from your model using `model.predict()` you may pass one single sample like `(1,28,28)` to get a prediction. So, The first dimension varies during the model life cycle. So it is set to `None`.

The first model shows `(32,10)` because you called it after `model.fit()` and you didn't specified `input_shape` in your first layer, so it inferences the shapes from training procedure. `model.fit()` sets `batch_size` to 32 as default. So, it shows the batch size.
But if you set `input_shape`, since you should not include the batch size, model will be created by `None` as the first dimension.