# How to interpret the shapes given by summary() in a sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm new to Keras.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

# model 1
model1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(3, "relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
], name="model1")


# model 2
model2 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(3, "relu", input_shape=(3, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
], name="model2")
```

`model1` is a sequential model that doesn't have any weights yet, so we need to feed it with data to solve that issue. In contrast, `model2` is a sequential model with `input_shape=(3,2)`, therefore it expects data with a shape of `(3, 2)`.

Then, I do this:

```
x1 = tf.ones((3, 2))
model1(x1) # this makes model1 infer its weights
```

The problem is when I try to run `summary()` method for both models:
[image: summary()]

How can I interpret this? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856244/why-does-model-summary-give-shape-none-when-input-shape-is-clear-and-fixed):

- `model2`'s input shape is `(None,3,2)`. `None` means the batch size, so we can give it any number of examples with shape `(3,2)` and the output is the same amount of examples with shape `(3,1)`.
- But, for `model1`, the input shape is `(3,2)`, hence I assume the batch size is 1? Maybe 3? Or it's also `None`? I don't understand.

Also, I found a new problem when I run the following examples:

```
# examples
x1 = tf.ones((3, 2))
x2 = tf.ones((3, 3, 2))

print(model1(x1)) #no problem
print(model1(x2)) #no problem
model1.summary()

print(model2(x1)) #this gives me an error! But input_shape=(3,2) in model2!!!!
print(model2(x2))
model2.summary()
```

Why is it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Model1's input_shape is not (3,2), it is (,2). The model considers 3 as the batch number. Because model2 accepts an input with the shape (batch_num, 3, 2), and on the other hand, you pass x1 with the shape (batch_num, 2) to it, it gives error.

Comment: If you don't see 'None' in your summary, that means your model has seen something as the batch number, which has caused misunderstanding for you.

Comment: Additionally, if you give an `input_shape`, the shape is always without the batch dimension. Hence why `model2(x1)` throws an error, it expected a batch dim. It's interesting that `model1(x1)` and `model1(x2)` works without errors. It seems that without an `InputLayer` (which is constructed with the `input_shape` argument for the first layer), there is no strict `input shape` required, and if the model can work with the input, it just does.